# What is the best way to handle nested futures?

Tags: fluent, vapor

I have users and groups in my system. Users belong to groups using a sibling relationship. I need to transform the Users/Groups into an Array of users/groups to return to the client. When I lookup a user I get a Future, if I then map the use and attempt to access its groups I get a Future.

What is the best way of handling nested futures so I can get to the actual data and munge it?

```swift
struct ReturnUserStruct {
   var userId: Int
   var primaryGroupName: String
}

let futureUsers = Users.query(on: request).all()

futureUsers.map { users in
    var returnUsersArray<returnUserStruct> = []

    users.ForEach { user in
      var returnUserStruct: ReturnUserStruct
      returnUserStruct.userId = user.id

// This a sibling relationship that returns a Future 
      primaryGroupFuture = user.primaryGroup
      primaryGroupFuture.map { group in 
        returnUserStruct.primaryGroupName = group.name
      }

      returnUsersArray.append(returnUserStruct)
   }

return returnUsersArray
```

This code doesn't work.  The map call are obviously scheduled asynchronously and returnUsersArray ends up empty.  I can rearrange this and get the user ids into the return array but haven't figured out a good way to get the groupName.

Comment: From my point of view it'd be better to execute raw SQL query and decode result into the right model.

Comment: Seems to defeat the purpose of an ORM. Let me twist the question a bit. Can fluent return a complete object with parents, children, siblings?  So I don’t need to go back to the DB and query relationships. I guess what I’m expecting is something more like activerecord.

Comment: As far as I know `Fluent4` will do that for you in `Vapor4`, but it is in alpha yet. In `Vapor3` fluent is not so powerful yet to fetch complete object `with parents, children, sibling` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Good to hear about Fluent4 and Vapor4.  Here is the solution I've settled on.

```swift
return Users.query(on: request)
            .all()
            .and(Group.find(user.primaryGroup).first())
            .map { (users, groupOptional) -> [ReturnUserStruct]

               guard let group = groupOptional else {
                   Abort(.notFound)
               }

               var returnArray: Array<ReturnUserStruct>

               users.forEach { user in
                  var returnUserStruct: ReturnUserStruct

                  returnUserStruct.userId = user.id
                  returnUserStruct.primaryGroupName = group.name

                  returnArray.append(returnUserStruct)
                }
            }
```

It seems to work, here's hope .and sticks around.

Thanks